# Pre-selecting items in a cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am having some trouble preselecting multiple items on load up. My goal is to have my app load and have the `cell` that my `scroll bar` is currently on be entirely pre-selected.

I currently have an image icon and text immediately below it, the issue is that my icon is pre-selected and highlighted on start but the text immediately below it is not unless I click to another cell and click back on the original cell. So I am aware in swift 3.0 the code will look like this to pre-select my icon but no text. I attempted a few things but came up with no success so that is why I erased any attempt to try and pre-select the text in this code. Been guessing for about four hours so I thought instead of wasting another day away I thought i'd ask!

```
    import UIKit

  class IntroBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .black
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
}()

let cellId = "cellId"
let imageNames = ["Ex1","Ex2","Ex3","Ex4"]
let titles = ["Ex1-1","Ex1-2","Ex1-3","Ex-1-4"]

var loginController: LoginController?


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)


    let selectIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    collectionView.selectItem(at: selectIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition())



    setupHorizontalBar()
}

var horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupHorizontalBar() {
    let horizontalBarView = UIView()
    horizontalBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
    horizontalBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(horizontalBarView)

    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)
    horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

    horizontalBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    horizontalBarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4).isActive = true
    horizontalBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:4).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    loginController?.scrollToMenuIndex(indexPath.item)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[indexPath.item])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    cell.imageLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titles[indexPath.item], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black])
    cell.imageLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cell.tintColor = .darkGray

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width / 4, height: frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}



class MenuCell: BaseCell {

let imageLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
   return label
}()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "Ex1")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    iv.tintColor = .darkGray
    return iv
}()

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = isHighlighted ? .white : .darkGray
        imageLabel.textColor = isHighlighted ? .white : .black
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? .white : .darkGray
        imageLabel.textColor = isSelected ? .white : .black
    }
}


    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        addSubview(imageLabel)
        addSubview(imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(33)]", views: imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(33)]", views: imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(75)]", views: imageLabel)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(50)]", views: imageLabel)
```

I apologize for my gnarly coding hack job... I just started a few days ago so i'm really just going by trial and error. Also any insight to cleaning up some of this code would be greatly appreciated!!

This is how it currently comes up

[This is the start up with only icon preselected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDWpE.jpg)

[This is when I switch to the 2nd icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZNah.jpg)

Wouldn't let me post my third image so I want image one to look like image two except initially on start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForItem` method add
`cell.isSelected = true`

Also if I need to select cells manually I do it in `cellForItem` method as well. So you don't need to hack around to manually specify the `indexPath` as you did because you have corresponding `indexPath` from the method itself.

Move your `collectionView.selectItem(at: selectIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition())` to the cell that you want to select at the moment when it is rendered.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt
                    indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, 
                                               for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[indexPath.item])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    cell.imageLabel.attributedText = ...
    cell.imageLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cell.tintColor = .darkGray

    if wantThisCellSelected == true {
       cell.isSelected = true
       collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false,
                                  scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition())
    } else {
       cell.isSelected = false
       collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
      return cell
   }
```

Comment: Adding the method `cell.isSelected = true` would select all the cells for me when rendered. I only needed specfically the first cell of string "Ex1" to be rendered on start. But!!

Comment: With that being said I moved `collectionView.selectItem(at: selectIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition())` with `let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0,section: 0)` to `cellForItem`  and BAM! It worked like a charm. I greatly apprecaite that!!  Insane how simple something is but can make you pull hair... Lol.

Comment: @UnKnownFubar another elegant way to do it, if you specifically need item 0 at section 0. You could use something like: `if indexPath.section == 0  && indexPath.item == 0 {  //select cell`

Comment: Ahhh! Oh alright, yeaaaaaaa. That looks good, I like that. Greatly appreciate it man!!